# How to parse a string that's in one index of an array?

Tags: c

I'm writing a program in C that receives two strings as input from the user on the command line. I know that when you use

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

it creates a pointer to the array that stores both arguments as argv[1] and argv[2]. Say the user inputs "hello" on the command line, and I want to access the individual characters in "hello", how can I do so if argv[1] gives me the whole string rather than individual characters?

Comment: `argv[x]` (for any valid `x`) is a *string*. You access individual elements of that like you do for any other string. You *have* encountered array of arrays before? Treat `argv` like an array of arrays.

Comment: @SaniJr: argv here is a 2 dimensional array. so in your example argv[1][0] is 'h', argv[1][1] is 'e' and so on. so you can run a for loop to the length of argv[1] and get each entry with argv[1][i].

Comment: @Deepak Thanks a lot that's what I was looking for. Didn't think of it as a 2D array.

Comment: `argv` is not a 2D array.  `argv` is a pointer, a pointer to a `char *`.

Comment: Sorry, it is not a 2D array. It is a pointer to a pointer. where each row can string can have its own size of character. it will not have the fixed dimension.

Comment: try `argv[i][j]` as a string is an array of characters, so an array of string pointers can be double subindexed.  BTW `argv` is a pointer to an array of pointers to `char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR- *When in doubt, check the data type.*

The type for `argv` is `char * []`, which decays to `char **`. Thus, `argv[n]` is of type `char *`.

You can index into `argv[n]`, like `argv[n][m]` to get the `char` elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can treat **char *argv[]** to a string array.

As the char * is a pointer which point to char array(also can treat as a string).

So the argv[0],argv[1].... are the char* data type, the argv[0][0] is char data type.